# jasmine spies on inherited methods (with typescript) not working as expected with toHaveBeenCalled()

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript, jasmine

I'm currently having an issue when spying on inherited methods for calls in typescript classes, where the toHaveBeenCalled() method is returning false, even though the method being spied upon is called. Look at the following scenario...

I have two classes, written in TypeScript

```
class Parent() {
    buyFood() {
        // buy food
    }
}

class Husband extends Parent {
    makeDinner() {
        super.buyFood();
        // make dinner;
    }
}
```

In my tests for the class Husband, i'm only concerned of testing the logic for making dinner, since the logic of the buy food of the super class is tested in its own test suite.

Hence, my tests looks like something of the following sort.

```
let husband:Husband = new Husband();

it('Should make a good dinner', () => {
    spyOn(husband, 'buyFood');
    husband.makeDinner();

    expect(husband.buyFood).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

Even though buyFood() is being called, the assertion is failing with an error saying that husband.buyFood() which is the method inherited from the Parent class has never been called.

How should I go about this issue, without having to assert the value changes by the buyFood() method call?

Comment: Is it documented anywhere that this is supported by the testing framework? Inheritance in JavaScript is fickle at best.

Comment: There does not seem to be any reference to inherited methods... From the docs "A spy can stub any function and tracks calls to it and all arguments."

Comment: Then perhaps it is not walking the prototype chain.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You have to understand the mechanics behind Typescript and the spying.

### First on Typescript ...

I'm ignoring the extra parens in `class Parent()`.

Typescript uses prototypal inheritance behind the curtain. Thus a prototype will copy the referenced properties from the "base class" to the new class. This is what the `for` loop does in the `__extends()` function.

This is the ES5 code your Typescript is translated to:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var Parent = (function () {
    function Parent() {
    }
    Parent.prototype.buyFood = function () {
        // buy food
    };
    return Parent;
}());
var Husband = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Husband, _super);
    function Husband() {
        return _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    }
    Husband.prototype.makeDinner = function () {
        _super.prototype.buyFood.call(this);
        // make dinner;
    };
    return Husband;
}(Parent));
```

You can translate typescript using this [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html).

Your `super` expression calls the `buyFood()` method of the parent class and not the method of the "inherited" `Husband`.

See the line

```
_super.prototype.buyFood.call(this);
```

and follow the `_super` reference.

### Now Jasmine Spies ...

A spy will replace the named function of the passed object by a spy function that will act as a proxy. That proxy can now track calls and, depending on the programmed behavior, control whether to call the original function, a fake, return a value or do nothing (default).

A *very* simplified `spyOn()` could look like this:

```
function spyOn(obj, fn) {
    var origFn = obj[fn],
        spy = function() {
            spy.calls.push(arguments);
        };

    spy.calls = [];

    obj[fn] = spy;
}
```

The [actual spy method](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.5.2/src/core/SpyRegistry.js) is much more complex though.

Your line

```
spyOn(husband, 'buyFood');
```

will actually replace the method in the *instance* of `Husband` by a spy. But, since the code calls the reference of the base class (the parent prototype) it's not the same function that you've just replaced.

### Solution

You should either call the `this` referenced method

```
class Husband extends Parent {
    makeDinner() {
        // call byFood() via this
        this.buyFood();
    }
}
```

... or spy on the parent prototype (`super`):

```
it('Should make a good dinner', () => {
    spyOn(Parent.prototype, 'buyFood');
    husband.makeDinner();

    expect(Parent.prototype.buyFood).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

Comment: Super!! Thanks a lot for the details explanation and solution! Really really grateful! :D

Comment: This was extremely helpful! In my case I have a method in a subclass that shadows a super class named method, so the `spyOn(Parent.prototype, 'methodName');` was perfect!

Comment: The solution worked perfectly! Most importantly, thanks for neatly explaining why it works :)

Comment: Wow. Love this solution!

Comment: @try-catch-finally what about if buyFood() is "protected" ?

Comment: Interesting question strix25 although this is beyond the scope of the question. However to make it short: we can still analyze what ECMAscript code is generated in the playground. In short: the generated ES code loses the visibility information. So with a ES dialect you should still be able to spy on these fields.

Answer (score 9):

When using **ES6**, the `Parent.prototype` will not work. Use the `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead.

This is what worked for me:

```
it('Should make a good dinner', () => {
    spyOn(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(husband)), 'buyFood');
    husband.makeDinner();

    expect(Parent.prototype.buyFood).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

Comment: works for me, but strange that `Object.getPrototypeOf()` must be called twice

Comment: i think this is because the 1st call will get you the prototype of the class and the 2nd call will get you the prototype's prototype

Comment: P.S. This solution works, except your example is missing a trailing parenthesis after 'husband'.

Comment: This is fantastic — thank you! I used this recently to spy on the `super` of a directive in Angular. Might not have gotten there without this gem <3

Answer (score 0):

```
const spy = spyOn(husband, 'buyFood');
husband.makeDinner();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: It would be good to add a sentence to explain what was wrong and what the proposed code is fixing

Answer (score 0):

The realworld example

```js
// test-utils.ts
function spyOnParentClassMethod<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> (
    instance: T,
    method: T[K] extends Function ? K : never,
){
    const parentInstance: T = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance));
    return spyOn(parentInstance, method);
}
```

```js
// spec.ts
const spy = spyOnParentClassMethod(husband, 'buyFood');
husband.makeDinner();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```